# Move text file from one folder to another folder using sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been using the following sql script to move file from one location to another .

```
EXEC
master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC
master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE

DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(500), @folderName varchar(100),@move varchar(100),@destinationpath varchar(50)

SET @folderName = 'Newfolder_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '') 

SET @cmd = 'mkdir C:\FileDestination\' + @folderName

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd   --- this will create folder(newfolder_mmddyyy)

set @destinationpath='C:\FileDestination\'+@folderName
set @move ='move c:\filesource\* '+ @destinationpath

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @move  ---this will move files to newly created folder
```

But it's showing the error as follows

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Can any one let me know the solution for this. Thanks Alot for your help !

Comment: You say you've been using this script to move files. So this has worked before? What changed?

Answer (score 0):

If "filesource" and "FileDestination" are example folder locations, then it could be that the variable for the move command is too small.  Try making it the same as `@cmd`, i.e. `@move nvarchar(500)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the access issue on the **filesource** folder, try giving full access to everyone on the folder.

I tried the exact code on my system and it works fine for me (moved test file).

[image]